# Clarett 4 Pre + RCA outs

Tags: rca

I got a Mackie Sub for my home studio and I use a Clarett 4 Pre Audio interface. I know the clarett Pre has RCA outs but it's only a single output port. I was wondering if it was possible to use RCA cables for sending audio to the Sub. [image: RCA cable] [image: Clarett Pre - back]

Comment: a) We don't know which Mackie sub you mean. b) Why do you think RCAs are going to be any help? Most of the Mackies use XLR, your Focusrite uses ¼ jacks, so you need a pair of those made up to get to the sub, then XLR to whatever your other speakers use after that. There's a simple way round all of this for sound engineers who are not electronically inclined… when you buy something you ask the shop to make up some cables to match your other gear. Takes all the guesswork out of it ;)

Comment: Isn't your sub connected to your main speakers? Usually the sub and speakers are fed from the same mixer outputs, you don't want to set up an extra output channel for the sub.

Comment: You also simply can't by just hooking up those cables. the rca ports use SPDIF which is a digital platform. So you need a DA converter to even use it as an audio ouput in the first place.